# Computed dependent field

Tags: entities

I have a node type (actually entityform type) with a term reference field. The terms has a description field (a long text with a HTML markup). I need to display the description of a selected term on a node edit form. Is it possible to show a description immediately after user selects new term from a list?

Comment: On the node edit form? I guess you'd need Ajax to show the description.

Comment: Is it possible to use an existing modules or I need to write my own one?

Comment: @Denis No module I know of provide this functionality. There are modules that lets you limit choices in one field basing on choice in another one, but none I know changes descriptions.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to add something like a viewfield, which shows all term descriptions. And to filter the view by a term reference field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's very easy to implement a computed dependent field. Suppose there is a term reference (field_section) on an edit form with YOUR_FORM_ID.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == YOUR_FORM_ID) {

    // Add an AJAX behaviour to field_section:
    // After you will select a new term on the edit form,
    // YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_alter and
    // _YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_section_callback will be called.
    $form['field_section'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax'] = array(
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' => '_YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_section_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'nomination-desc-wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade'
    );

    // Add a wrapper for our computed dependent field.
    // At the begining it will be invisible
    $form['nomination_desc_container'] = array(
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#weight' => 2,
      '#attributes' => array('id' => array('nomination-desc-wrapper')),
    );

    // Add a computed dependent field. It will be shown as a text
    $form['nomination_desc_container']['nomination_desc'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
    );

    // This code will be executed during form creation and
    // during each AJAX-call
    if (isset($form_state['values']['field_section'])) {

      // Find taxonomy term
      $tid = $form_state['values']['field_section'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];
      $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

      // Show it's description
      $form['nomination_desc_container']['nomination_desc']['#markup'] = $term->description;

      // Display description wrapper
      $form['nomination_desc_container']['#type'] = 'container';
    }
  }
}

// Just return new wrapper body
function _YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_section_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['nomination_desc_container'];
}
```